# How to determine whether add-on subscription of Windows Store app is in trial period or in paid period

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, subscription, add-on

I am working on adding add-on subscription to my Desktop Bridge app published in Windows store using [Windows.Services.Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.services.store) APIs.

I created a test add-on of subscription for 3 month period with 1 week trial period. I can get a [StoreAppLicence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.services.store.storeapplicense) instance by `StoreContext.GetAppLicenseAsync` method calling from my app and then from its `AddOnLicenses` property, find a [StoreLicense](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.services.store.storelicense) instance whose `SkuStoreId` matches the StoreId of the test add-on in the beginning. But there is no clue whether this subscription is in trial period or in paid (full) period because it does not have `IsTrial` property like StoreAppLicence.

So I would like to how to determine whether the subscription is in trial period or in paid period for showing my users the status of subcription in my app.

**Update**

I was not clear enough but I am asking about the case after the current user has "purchased" add-on subscription as free trial. I would like to know how to determine whether the trial period has not finished yet or the trial period has passed already and the subscription has moved to paid (full) period.

Probably I can achieve it by storing the data on when the user "purchased" the subscription in local and comparing it with the current date but it seems not ideal because there might be a chance of inconsistency with the data managed by  Windows Store server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably I found a solution.

`IsTrial` property of [StoreCollectionData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.services.store.storecollectiondata) obtained by `StoreContext.GetUserCollectionAsync` method provides the information what I need. In addition, the StoreCollectionData also includes `AcquiredDate` property which indicates the purchase date of subscription add-on and is useful to calculate the expiration date on your own. In my experience, `ExpirationDate` property of StoreLicense obtained by `StoreContext.GetAppLicenseAsync` method seems not accurate (3 days later than actual expiration date).

The sample code would be as follows.

```
public enum LicenseStatus
{
    Unknown = 0,
    Trial,
    Full
}

private static StoreContext _context;

public static async Task<(string storeId, LicenseStatus status, DateTimeOffset acquiredDate)[]> GetSubscriptionAddonStatusesAsync()
{
    if (_context is null)
        _context = StoreContext.GetDefault();

    StoreProductQueryResult queryResult = await _context.GetUserCollectionAsync(new[] { "Durable" });
    if (queryResult.ExtendedError != null)
        throw queryResult.ExtendedError;

    IEnumerable<(string, LicenseStatus, DateTimeOffset)> Enumerate()
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, StoreProduct> pair in queryResult.Products)
        {
            StoreSku sku = pair.Value.Skus.FirstOrDefault();
            StoreCollectionData data = sku?.CollectionData;
            if (data != null)
            {
                LicenseStatus status = data.IsTrial ? LicenseStatus.Trial : LicenseStatus.Full;
                yield return (pair.Key, status, data.AcquiredDate);
            }
        }
    }

    return Enumerate().ToArray();
}
```

On the other hand, there still exists a weird thing on `StoreContext.GetUserCollectionAsync` method. It only provides the information on the latest add-on while from its explanation, it should provide the information on all add-ons. Therefore, if you want to check multiple add-ons, this method will not be enough.

Comment: Yes, u r right GetAppLicenseAsync , GetUserCollectionAsync, so many confusing methods and none gives all and accurate information required.  I found that GetAppLicenseAsync only returns "Subscription" addon details that user has purchased and that's strange.        Ref:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71468965/microsoft-store-api-unable-to-get-license-information-of-all-addons

Answer (score 0):

C# example:

```
subscriptionStoreProduct = await GetSubscriptionProductAsync();
if (subscriptionStoreProduct == null)
{
    return;
}
// Check if the first SKU is a trial and notify the customer that a trial is available.
// If a trial is available, the Skus array will always have 2 purchasable SKUs and the
// first one is the trial. Otherwise, this array will only have one SKU.
StoreSku sku = subscriptionStoreProduct.Skus[0];
if (sku.SubscriptionInfo.HasTrialPeriod)
{
    // You can display the subscription trial info to the customer here. You can use 
    // sku.SubscriptionInfo.TrialPeriod and sku.SubscriptionInfo.TrialPeriodUnit 
    // to get the trial details.
}
else
{
    // You can display the subscription purchase info to the customer here. You can use 
    // sku.SubscriptionInfo.BillingPeriod and sku.SubscriptionInfo.BillingPeriodUnit
    // to provide the renewal details.
}
```

Derive from sample [Purchase a subscription add-on](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/enable-subscription-add-ons-for-your-app#purchase-a-subscription-add-on) and Class [StoreSku Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.services.store.storesku)

**Update**

If users can use subscription, there are only two possibilities, one for a trial period and one that they have already purchased.
The method (*GetSubscriptionProductAsync*) in the code gets the subscriptions which users can use, you could see the details in the sample(**[Purchase a cubscription add-on](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/enable-subscription-add-ons-for-your-app#purchase-a-subscription-add-on)**). The property [HasTrialPeriod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.services.store.storesubscriptioninfo#properties) gets a value that indicates whether the subscription contains a trial period.

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, I am not asking how to determine if an add-on contains trial period. Please see update.

Comment: Thank you for your update. I have already tried all samples. So, you mean that HasTrialPeriod property of the first StoreSku included in StoreProduct obtained by GetSubscriptionProductAsync method in the sample is True when the user purchased the add-on and its trial period has not ended yet? I found that before I purchased the add-on, the StoreProduct has two StoreSku; the first is for trial (HasTrialPeriod is True) and the second is for full (HasTrialPeriod is False) and after I purchased, the StoreProduct has only one StoreSku which is identical to the second one (HasTrialPeriod is False).

Comment: I think this is expected behavior explained in comments in the sample. I cannot figure out how I can make use of HasTrialPeriod property for my purpose.

Comment: Could you tell me what your the purpose is to distinguish subscription's trial period and purchased use?

Comment: It is exactly my purpose. Let's say, if an user purchases an add-on subscription described in my question on Feb 17, the user will be given one week free trial period. The trial period will end on Feb 23. If the user does not cancel the subscription until Feb 23, the billing period will automatically start on Feb 24 and the user will be billed. I would like to distinguish whether the user is in trial period (after Feb 17 and before Feb 24) or in paid (billed) period (after Feb 24).